# how can we make url starts with# using attribute routing in mvc5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I want to create a url which starts with # like `localhost:/#somename`. Can anyone help me?

i tried with custom route constraint,i did not get

```
//localhost:/#testing
[Route(@"{x:regex([^#]*)}testing")]
public ActionResult testingyash(string x)
{
  return View();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cant have a url like that. The `#` symbol is a [Fragment Identifier](http://www.w3.org/DesignIssues/Fragment.html). Its used by browsers to identify a section in page. Anything following the `#` is not even sent to the server.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need routing for # value? Those are client-side values.

try `Url.Action`

```
return Redirect(Url.Action("Index", "Home") + "#testing");
```