# How to Create a url like localhost:/#index in attribute routing?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

i tried like this

`[Route("{Name:regex(^([[punc:]))}index")]
public void index()
{...
}`

can you Please correct this?
and please let me know how to get url starts with '#'

Comment: possible duplicate of [how can we make url starts with# using attribute routing in mvc5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27542532/how-can-we-make-url-starts-with-using-attribute-routing-in-mvc5)

Answer (score 0):

This US not possible because the URL f  fragment (the part after #) is not used at all in ASP.net. You won't find it in HttpRequest object either.

Although it would be quite handy, it is simply not available for use on  the Server side.